# Getting Xml from an embedded code in Xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-serialization

I want to transform my Xml with a Xslt file. Can I access to the Xml that is transforming with Xslt in an embedded code piece using C#.

```
<![CDATA[
    public string GetSomething(string path)
    {
        // Get the whole Xml that is transforming
        // And do something with it    
        // return result
    }
]]>

<xsl:value-of select ="GetSomething(courier:_appointment)"/>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* some scripting support inside xslt, via [`<msxsl:script>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256042.aspx), however: it is probably a better idea to use an *extension object*. Basically, you write a regular C# object (although you need to mark it as COM-callable, IIRC), and add it via `XsltArgumentList`, in particular [`AddExtensionObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx) - and in the process associate it with a particular urn. Your xslt then declares an xml namespace-alias for the url (i.e. `xmlns:myExtension="blah blah"`), and uses `myExtension:someMethod(...)` in the code.

There is a full example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort